# Fixing image that scrolls into view

Tags: css, image, styling, fixed

Any idea how I could fix an image to the bottom of the PAGE (not screen) and once the page scrolls to the bottom it drops behind an image that is fixed at the base. This can be done obviously with a position absolute and bottom: 0 BUT my backcroung image is fixed and responsive.

Any thoughts?

I tried position fixed but it is always in view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this: http://dabblet.com/gist/3748749?

Comment: jklm313 thanks for this. I did indeed mean that yeah. Thanks!